# Let $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}|0<x<1\}$ and $B=\{x\in \mathbb{R}|1<x<5\}$ .Show A and B have same cardinality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}|0<x<1\}$ and $B=\{x\in \mathbb{R}|1<x<5\}$ .Show A and B
have same cardinality

My idea: is we prove that there is bijection between A and B so that they have same cardinality

Comment: What does "having bisection between real intervals" mean?

Comment: Well, "bijection" and not "bisection", but otherwise yes, that's how it's done. Do you know a function that will do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: define

$$\phi:A\to B\;,\;\;\;\phi(t)=1+4t$$

Comment: @DonAntonio....thanks